# Docker container ports setup incorrectly

Tags: python, docker, fastapi, uvicorn

I have a simple application I want to dockerize. It is a simple API that works correctly when I run it on my machine and is accessible on http://127.0.0.1:8000/
This is the dockerfile I created

```
FROM python:3.6-slim-stretch
WORKDIR /code
COPY requirements.txt /code
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt --no-cache-dir
COPY . /code
CMD ["uvicorn", "main:app", "--reload"]
```

I then create the image using this command **sudo docker build -t test .**

And then run it this way **sudo docker run -d -p  8000:8000 test**

The problem is that I cant access it http://127.0.0.1:8000/ even though I don't know the problem

PS: when I check my container ports I get 0.0.0.0:8000->8000/tcp, :::8000->8000/tcp

I want to know what is causing this problem and how to fix it.

Comment: try exposing the port 8000  as `EXPOSE 8000`  in your dockerfile

Comment: Doesn't help I had it in the dockerfile before but took it out as it wasn't needed.

Comment: Some other random notes on this Dockerfile: `--reload` means auto-reloading code when it changes. Given you're copying the code in, you probably don't want that, it's only something you'd use in development. `stretch` is very old, use `bullseye` instead. Python 3.6 is about to be end of life, switch to 3.9.

Comment: @ItamarTurner-Trauring Thanks for the notes I'll do the necessary changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default `uvicorn` listens on `127.0.0.1`. `127.0.0.1` inside the container is private,it doesn't participate in portforwarding.

The solution is to do `uvicorn --host 0.0.0.0`, e.g.:

```
CMD ["uvicorn", "main:app", "--reload", "--host", "0.0.0.0"]
```

For an explanation of why this is the case, with diagrams, see https://pythonspeed.com/articles/docker-connection-refused/

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it for me.

Answer (score -1):

1. Try accessing http://0.0.0.0:8000
2. What do you mean "I can access it"? Do you get permission denied?
   404? what error are you seeing?
3. Try accessing inside the container: `$docker exec -it test bash` and
   see if the program is running inside of it: `$curl http://0.0.0.0:8000`.
4. Try curling into the container's explicit ip.
   get the ip: `docker inspect -f '{{range.NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' test`

Comment: 1/ Doesn't work either

2/ I get "This site can’t be reached"

3/ Yes it is running 

4/ I didn't understand that

Comment: Ok, 3 tells us the program is ok, and the problem is with networking.<br/>
regarding 4:<br/>
every docker container you run has an external IP. you can curl that IP on port 8000 to see what you get as an answer. If this answer is what you expect, than the problem is with the call not moving from localhost:8000 into container:8000.<br/>If the curl is wrong, this means the ports are not properly mapped.